# Calculating mean and variance of normal distribution restricted to interval

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, mean, descriptive-statistics, range

If one set a lower and an upper limit on the normal density, is it statistically valid to calculate the mean and Standard deviation of that normal variate. If yes, how can we do that in R?

In a more elaborate  way, consider a variable which is standard normal, (mean = 0 , standard deviation =1). This variable can take any values from  [-4, 4].

If I want to restrict the range from where the variable can take the values ; the new range is [200, 800]. Now what will be the new mean and standard deviation of this new variable with restricted range.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "lower and upper limit of the normal random variable"? Minimum and maximum of a normal sample?

Comment: @Xi'an, yes. Theoretically normal variable can take any value form -inf to inf.I need  to restrict my random variable within say,  200 to 800.

P.S. I do not have the all the sample values. All I know is that Maximum and minimum of the variable.

Comment: It's not clear how the maximum and minimum you describe are being obtained. Can you please be explicit? Answers will depend heavily on how this works.

Comment: Please rephrase your question using [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$.

Comment: Apart from the minimum and the maximum of the sample, do you know the *size* of the sample, that is, the number of sample values which these maximum and minimum are based on?

Comment: "In more elaborate way, Consider a variable which is standard normal, (mean = 0 , standard deviation =1). This variable can take any values from [-4, 4]." It can take values above 4 and below -4 also! The tails of a normal distribution go to infinity on both directions, albeit with minute probability density outside [4,-4].

Comment: @Did, there is no sample. I just need a transformation, which can transform the values coming from a standard normal variable which ranges from the -4 to 4 transformed into a variable which is again normal which ranges from 200 to 800

Comment: When you talk about restricting the range, were you thinking of the [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)?

Comment: @Silverfish, I completely agree that it can take the values outside [-4,4] ; but I do not need those values as the range -3 to 3 only cover more that 99% of values.

Comment: @Silverfish, yes you can consider it on very similar lines.

Comment: If it is a standard normal variable, you don't get to choose the support - while even -2 to 2 contains >95% of the probability, -4 and 4 are not lower and upper limits. That's why I wonder if you're thinking of a truncated variable instead of a standard one? That way you *can* impose strict lower and upper limits.

Comment: my mistake, please truncate that standard part. :) May be I was using the wrong terminology, consider it as a truncated normal with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

Comment: @Irri A problem quite different from the one the first version of the question was pointing to.

Comment: @Did, I just made it specific. the transformation part might have made it look deviating from the first version

Comment: @Irri "I just made it specific". No. But no big deal.

Comment: The title of this question still represents the original question, not the very different question that the body has been changed to. That should probably be edited also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a standard normal distribution and truncate it to an interval $[a,b]$, its density becomes$$\dfrac{\exp\{-x^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}$$ Its mean is$$\dfrac{\int_a^b x\exp\{-x^2/2\}\,\text{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}=\dfrac{[-\exp\{-x^2/2\}]_a^b}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}=\dfrac{\exp\{-a^2/2\}-\exp\{-b^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}$$ and the second moment is
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\int_a^b x^2\exp\{-x^2/2\}\,\text{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}&= 
\dfrac{\int_a^b x[-\exp\{-x^2/2\}]'\,\text{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}\qquad\text{integrate by parts}\\
&= \dfrac{[-x\exp\{-x^2/2\}]_a^b}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}+\dfrac{\int_a^b \exp\{-x^2/2\}\,\text{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]]}\\
&= \dfrac{a\exp\{-a^2/2\}-b\exp\{-b^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}+1\\
\end{align*}
In case this does not sound a natural solution, you can always check by simulation:

```
> a=4;b=8
> truno=qnorm(runif(10^5)*(pnorm(b)-pnorm(a))+pnorm(a))
> mean(truno)
[1] 4.225641
> (dnorm(a)-dnorm(b))/(pnorm(b)-pnorm(a))
[1] 4.225607
> mean(truno^2)
[1] 17.90303
> (a*dnorm(a)-b*dnorm(b))/(pnorm(b)-pnorm(a))+1
[1] 17.90243
```

Comment: Thank you. Considering the mean 0 and std dev= 1 (assuming std norm) but with variable restricted in range -4 to 4, mean comes out to be 0 and var 0.9989.

For time being I will approximate variance to 1.
Now Suppose I assume that Xt follows truncated normal (-4<X<4) with mean 0 and variance 1.

so if I transform this truncated normal variable to Yt (where Yt = aXt + b; a and b are integers).

Now, considering that minimum  and maximum value of the Xt is -4 and 4 respectively.

we ll get the two equations 200 = -4*a +b and 800 = 4*a+b

solving a and b we get b=500 and a =75

Comment: Isn't it  same like doing something called obtaining the parameters of transformed normal
where Xt -> N(0,1) then Yt -> N(b, a)
I am I correct?