# Expected value of X^3 for a normal distribution given it has limits?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, truncated-normal-distribution

What is the expected value of $X^3$ with in limits for a normal distribution? In other words, I am looking for solution of $E(X^3 \mid a\leq X \leq b)$.

Comment: Please decide where you want to ask. Avoid [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3741323/321264).

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward via the mgf found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: @StubbornAtom I will delete my question at Math Overflow

Comment: @JarleTufto: Thanks but to get this for $E(X^3)$?

Comment: Pointless, since you were guided to a solution in the comments there. Wonder what's the hurry for getting an answer.

Comment: TBH, I could not understand the answer and further, I doubted if that forum is hard-core math community. I realize now mathoverflow is the dedicated community.

Comment: The solution is obtained through a minor variation of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264889 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136247.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136253/1352), truncating a standard normal distribution between $a$ and $b$ gives a random variable with density
$$\dfrac{\exp\{-x^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}.$$

The expectation you are looking for therefore is
$$\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}\int_a^b x^3\exp\{-x^2/2\} \,dx \\
=& \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)]}\bigg((a^2+2)\exp(-a^2/2)-(b^2+2)\exp(-b^2/2)\bigg) \end{align*}$$
[with an integration from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E3*exp%28-x%5E2%2F2%29).

We can test this result using a little simulation in R. The following code gives the same output (up to sampling variation) for different values of `aa` and `bb`:

```
aa <- -1
bb <- 2

set.seed(1)
xx <- rnorm(1e6)
mean(xx[xx>aa & xx<bb]^3)

((aa^2+2)*exp(-aa^2/2)-(bb^2+2)*exp(-bb^2/2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*(pnorm(bb)-pnorm(aa)))
```

The formula is [easily extended](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E3*exp%28-%28x-mu%29%5E2%2F%282*sigma%5E2%29%29) to a non-standard normal $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.